# Rewrite if substring is found in any part of URL

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

`index.php?action=affiliate/registration`

`/affiliate/registration/`

I would like to rewrite this urls to `index.php?action=notfound` because `affiliate/registration` substring is found in any part of URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
# Don't rewrite if the request is for a real file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)(affiliate|registration)+(.*) index.php?action=notfound [QSA,L]
```

If there's always a `/` before, I would rather do:

```
# Don't rewrite if the request is for a real file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/(affiliate|registration)+(.*) index.php?action=notfound [QSA,L]
```

If there's always a `/` after, I would rather do:

```
# Don't rewrite if the request is for a real file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)(affiliate|registration)+/(.*) index.php?action=notfound [QSA,L]
```

If there's always a `/` before and after, I would rather do:

```
# Don't rewrite if the request is for a real file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/(affiliate|registration)+/(.*) index.php?action=notfound [QSA,L]
```